# Enzyme simulate mousedown event in react component

Tags: reactjs, events, jestjs, enzyme, simulate

This is my first unit test and i am stuck to test mouse event. I have a div where on mouse down I fetch offsetX and offsetY and store that value in state.

```
<div
      className={`outputCanvasHolder ${
        this.props.output.selection === "CLICK"
          ? "showOutput"
          : "hideOutput"
      }`}
      onMouseDown={e => {
        this.handleMouseDown(e.nativeEvent)
      }}
      onMouseMove={e => {
        this.handleMouseMove(e.nativeEvent)
      }}
      onMouseUp={e => {
        this.handleMouseUp(e.nativeEvent)
      }}
    >My div</div>

handleMouseDown = primitive => {
this.setState(
  {
    dragStartX: primitive.offsetX,
    dragStartY: primitive.offsetY
  }
)
```

}

Now I want to test it using jest

```
it("mouse down event", () => {
props.output.selection = "CLICK"
const wrapper = shallow(<ReAlignedImageCanvas {...props} />)
const canvasDiv = wrapper.find(".showOutput")
console.log(canvasDiv.debug())
canvasDiv.simulate("mousedown", {
  target: {
    name: "dragStartX",
    value: 100
  }
})
expect(wrapper.find(".test"))
expect(wrapper.find(".test-100").length).to.equal(1)
```

})

But I am getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetX' of undefined. Can you please tell me how to test this event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here asyn await is needed to make mouseDown event synchronus.
Component should be mount.
Event should be a mock function.
Mouse event should be invoked to the element.
Offset values should be mocked.

```
 it("mouse down event", async () => {
    const mockCallBack = jest.fn()
    props.output.selection = "CLICK"
    props.canvas.allPrimitives = true
    const wrapper = mount(
      <ReAlignedImageCanvas onMouseDown={mockCallBack} {...props} />
    )

    await wrapper.find(".showOutput").invoke("onMouseDown")(
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          offsetX: 200,
          offsetY: 180
        }
      },
      9000
    )
    expect(wrapper.state("dragStartX")).toBe(200)
    expect(wrapper.state("dragStartY")).toBe(180)
  })
```